# XSLT remove some child node first then remove parent node if there are no child node left

Tags: templates, xslt, nodes, parent-child

I just spent a few days looking for a solution without finding any solution.

So I have this xml upon which I want to apply two `<xsl:template match="">`, the second depending of the first one:

```
<xml>

 <parent>
  <data1>data</data1>
  <data2>data</data2>
  <childNodes>
   <childNode>
    <child> Value 2 </child>
   </childNode>
  </childNodes>
 </parent>

 <parent>
  <data1>data</data1>
  <data2>data</data2>
  <childNodes>
   <childNode>
    <child> Value 1 </child>
   </childNode>
   <childNode>
    <child> Value 2 </child>
   </childNode>
   <childNode>
    <child> Value 3 </child>
   </childNode>
  </childNodes>
 </parent>

</xml>
```

My objective is to:

- First remove  when child!='Value 1' using this:
  `<xsl:template match="childNode[child!='Value 1']/>`
- And secondly, remove the entirety of the parent node if there are no more  inside, using this:
  `<xsl:template match="xml/parent[not(childNodes/childNode)]"/>`

I could not find any way to apply both `<xsl:template match="">` one after the other, most often there is a way to combine both of them within a single one. I did not manage this here

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Ben

Comment: Which XSLT processor or which version of XSLT do you use? XSLT 3 and where-populated might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done in the order you want, because in the [XSLT processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Processing-Model) the parent node is processed before the child node.

However, you can easily remove parent nodes that do not have children (or rather descendants) other than the ones that will be removed:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent[not(childNodes/childNode/child='Value 1')]"/>

<xsl:template match="childNode[child!='Value 1']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```